# C# Graphics not drawing rectangles where required

Tags: c#, graphics, size

I am creating a Graphics Form where objects with coordinates x,y are being drawn into the Graphics. It works properly for small x and y, but when I want to draw them in different place (f.e. x = 500, y = 300) they disappear.

```
 public WindowHandler()
        {
            dc = this.CreateGraphics();

            this.Size = new Size(sizeX, sizeY); // 800x600
            startSimulation = new Button
            {
                // button properties
            };

            this.Controls.Add(startSimulation);
            startSimulation.Click += new EventHandler(StartSimulationClick);

        }

        private void CreationsMethods()
        {
            creations.PaintAllAnimals(dc);
        }

        public void PaintAllAnimals(Graphics g)
        {
            foreach (var animal in ecoStructure.world.animals)
            {
                animal.PaintAnimal(g);
            }
        }

        public void PaintAnimal(Graphics graphics)
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, 3, 3);
            Pen pen = new Pen(colour);
            graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rectangle);
            graphics.FillRectangle(colour, rectangle);
        }
```

I want to put all the objects onto the window. Is there any way to make the Graphics "bigger"? Do I need to make another one? Or should I use different tool to draw rectangles?

Comment: where are you drawing on?

Comment: I use everything I posted in code. dc is Graphics, which I use to draw (PaintAnimal method). I also use using `System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;`

Comment: It looks like this: [link](https://imgur.com/a/gGkC1fU). As you can see, the right rectangle is "cutted" in middle, because it is supposed to be painted in this particular coord (x,y). There also should be more of them (15 in summary), but they are being cutted from this Graphics.

Comment: The problem is that you are using `CreateGraphics` which you should not do.  All painting in a Winform app should be done in the `OnPaint` override or the `Paint` event handler.  Any painting you do using `CreateGraphics` will be overwritten the next time Windows decides to repaint the window.  As an aside, you are creating a `Pen` object and never disposing of it.  This is a handle leak.

Comment: Alright! Thank you very much. I will read about that and change it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Chris Dunaway for posting an answer in comment.
So I deleted the CreateCraphics, and instead of that i am now using an OnPaint method. It works slowly, but works. So I will try to make it as fast as i can. For now, I just created this. NextStepClick is how I use the OnPaint to paint the rectangles.

```
private void CreationsMethods(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            dc = e.Graphics;
            base.OnPaint(e);
            creations.PaintAllAnimals(dc);
        }
private void NextStepClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Refresh();
            picBox.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(CreationsMethods);
        }
```

Comment: `picBox.Paint +=..` Do not hook up the event more than once!!! (At least not without unhooking it again.) A Click event seems to be a dubious place..

Comment: How do I "unhook" it?

Comment: `picBox.Paint -=..` But, as I said, best hook it it up once, as you do any other event, like mouseclicks or selectionchanged etc.. __If it is hooked up multiple times it will run multiple times__, which might be the reason why you perceive slowness..

Comment: @TaW the correct term of `hooking` or `unhooking` is `subscribing` and `unsubscribing`. @LauraAlice seemed confused by the term `unhook`

Comment: Well, yes `subscribing` is the formal term, but that doesn't make 'hooking up an event' incorrect; it is used widely, including on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2). The confusion is more likely due to being so new.

Comment: Oh yeah, thats how I understood it. Thanks for all the advices, it works smoothly now!